# programmatically Copy Dynamic lib(.dylib) in Usr/local/lib path

Tags: xcode, cocoa, dynamic-library

I need to copy the C++(.dylib) dynamic lib in usr/local/lib path via my framework project. In normal Application project I set the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH working fine. but framework project not working.
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question: are you having problems copying the `.dylib`, or are you having problems linking to it?

Comment: i have a problem in programatically copy the .dylib file.

Comment: And you want to copy it to the global `usr/local/lib` folder? I'd recommend copying it to the built bundle and reference it from there, you'll make it more portable this way.